# python PIL: Displaying issue when create PNG image without Alpha channel

Tags: python, image, png, python-imaging-library

I'm using Python and PIL to create a non-transparent RGB image and save it as PNG format.

But when I display it, the RGB of each pixel changes around its correct value. (I test by capturing a screenshot with no scale and print out the RGB value in this screenshot) The RGB value of original image is exactly correct, only value in screenshot changes.

```
im = Image.new("RGB",(length,length),"black")
set RGB value for certain point
im.save(image.png,"PNG")
```

However, if I create the image in RGBA format, **without setting the Alpha value,** and save it also as PNG format, the RGB value on the screenshot is exactly correct.

```
im = Image.new("RGBA",(length,length),"black")
set RGB value for certain point
im.save(image.png,"PNG")
```

I'm wondering why there happens the difference since it is not a transparent image.

I asked on Quora and [discussed with someone](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-pixels-RGB-value-change-if-I-store-a-PNG-image-without-alpha-value-when-checking-its-screenshot-No-change-for-RGBA-one/answer/Dale-Thomas-8) who told me it is not a issue/feature of PNG.

Also I checked the PIL source code related to PNG saving. From [line726](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/6a296a45c13c4807abdce207be1c57dd2c890dcf/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py#L726) I noticed for a non-transparent PNG image there is no default value for Alpha channel if the image is not in RGBA format image.

So I'm wondering what happens when PIL tries so save a RGB format image into PNG file with no default Alpha value?

Or is it the system's issue when displaying an PNG file without Alpha channel?

---

P.S. I'm using PNG image as a media to transfer file, so the RGB value should be exactly correct to decode.

and in case you need to see all my code:
https://github.com/lanyusea/py_imageFileConverter

Thanks!